# Write a function which takes a dataset and categorical variable names as input and returns dataset with dummy variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a function which takes a dataset and categorical variable names as input and returns dataset with dummy variables for that categorical variable.

This is the function which I wrote:

```
dummy_func <- function(df_name, df_column, df_out){  
     full_col_name=paste("df_name","df_column", sep="$")  
      for (level in (unique(full_col_name))){  
        df_name[paste("dummy", level, sep="_")] = ifelse(full_col_name == level, 1, 0)  
      }  
    }
```

But when I am passing the following arguments while calling the function; I am getting a NULL value.

```
b=dummy_func(grp_new_prof2, "Job_profile")
```

The dataframe is as shown below:

```
> grp_new_prof2  
         job      y Freq  Job_profile  
1         admin. no 0.88     Salaried  
2    blue-collar no 0.93    Big-Shots  
3   entrepreneur no 0.92    Big-Shots  
4      housemaid no 0.91 Home-Service  
5     management no 0.86     Salaried  
6        retired no 0.77 Non-Salaried  
7  self-employed no 0.88     Salaried  
8       services no 0.91 Home-Service  
9        student no 0.71 Non-Salaried  
10    technician no 0.89     Salaried  
11    unemployed no 0.84 Non-Salaried  
12       unknown no 0.88      Unknown  
>
```

Can anyone please help with the same?

Comment: I'm wondering if you are reinventing the `model.matrix` function which is paired with the `~` function. Almost all regression functions use them "under the hood" meaning that such an operation is likely to be a waste of time and a serious distraction from getting useful work done, unless of course this is an exercise for a homework problem. I suggest you back up one stage and say what you are hoping to actually do.

Comment: The code is not working because `full_col_name` contains a string (`"grp_new_prof2$Job_profile"`), which is a string, not an object. Replace `full_col_name` with `df_name[,df_column]`. But yeah, like @42- pointed out, normally you don't have to make dummies yourself.

Comment: Hi 42, @Laterow,  Thank you for your comments...It's an assignment and hence am trying to reinvent the wheel.. However, Laterow, I tried as per your comments but still getting null.... `> dummy_func <- function(df_name, df_column, df_out){
+   # df_name[,df_column]
+   #full_col_name=paste("df_name","df_column", sep="$")
+   #  class(df_name)
+   #  class(df_column)
+   for (level in (unique(df_name[,df_column]))){
+     df_name[paste("dummy", level, sep="_")] = ifelse(df_name[,df_column] == level, 1, 0)
+   }
+ }
> b=dummy_func(grp_new_prof2, "Job_profile")
> b
NULL`

Comment: If it's an assignment, you'll have to figure out the rest yourself.. ;) Stackoverflow isn't meant for homework help, you have teachers for that. Although to be fair, you did come a long way and the fix is pretty easy. Read [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html) a bit more carefully and you should be able to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Laterow :) Just needed a hint where to follow from.. Thanks for ur time and support again :)